# How can write on click function on same button in two js file

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I want to check a form by two levels. 
1st level: preventDefault if unfilled any required field.
2nd level: if 1st is okay and is going to be submitted then I want to do ajax with the form data.
Here is my form:

```
<form  id="form_sample_1" class="form-horizontal normalForm">
                <div id="info-container2">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group c_name_container">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" id="c_name"  class="form-control required" placeholder="Type your Name here"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group c_email_container">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input  id="c_email" class="form-control required" type="email" placeholder="Type your Email Address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            <button type="button" id="start_chat" class="btn green">Start Chat</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

My 1st level Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".normalForm button", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
       if(noError){
                    $(this).closest('form').unbind('submit').submit();
                }

});
```

Here noError has Boolean value true or false. If error exist its value is false otherwise its value is true.I do not show all codes due to simplicity. My code works fine. But after this validation succeeded I want to prevent normal submission again. I want to do this by 'start_chat' id as follows:

```
   $('#start_chat').click(function(){
// if first level validation is okay then Do Ajax with form values. 
});
```

In this situation `$('#start_chat').click(function(){` and `$(document).on("click", ".normalForm button", function (event)` refer same button and occurs an ambiguity problem. And one possible solution is  wringing code of 2nd level js into 1st level js. But in my situation I want to use first level js for general purpose and 2nd level is more specific purpose. Any idea

Comment: Your second bit of code is entirely invalid. it should be `.click(function(){..});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting $('.normalForm button) and binding your first level logic to its click event, add a specific class to the buttons that you want to execute the first level. So just name those specific buttons $('.firstlevelbutton') or something. Then you can bind events to $('#start_chat') and do whatever you want there.